# Element centered with position:absolute plus zero padding

Tags: css

I have an a-element that I'm centering in a bootstrap column with this...

```
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

It centers correctly, but the bootstrap column takes up half the page and because I've had to use "left: 0" and "right:0", the a-element also takes up half the page (even though the text it contains is very small).  This is frustrating because the user can hover nowhere near the text itself and it will highlight like it's being hovered over.

I've experimented with "display:inline-block !important", "padding:0px !important", and "margin:0px !important", but none of them work while I have the left/right attributes in there (but of course as soon as I remove left/right the absolute positioning centering stops working).

Really appreciate any ideas about how to properly combine an absolute positioning effect without having oversized elements - thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with what you want?

Comment: Why did you use `left:0` and `right:0`? Maybe it's easier to find a different way to do that. When you use both, the left edge of the `a` element will reach the left edge of the parent element, and vice versa, so the `a` element will be the same width as the parent.

Comment: put the a element in a container div, put the css style you posted on that container and than style the a element

Comment: thanks all for the feedback - @user3528269 - your suggestion nailed it completely (and sorry if the question was a little vague)